# Required initializers in Swift

Tags: swift, inheritance, initialization

I have a question regarding required initializers and inheritance.

Here's my inheritance diagram:

```
TreeNode
  + ValueNode<ValueType>
    + [final] ConstantNode<ValueType>
    + UnaryNode<OperandType,ResultType>
  + ActionNode
    + [final] SequenceNode
    + [final] LoopNode
```

In the base class `TreeNode` I have two initializers (both of them are required):

```
1. public required init(factory: RandomTreeFactory, maximumDepth: Int) 
2. public required init(id: Int, maximumDepth: Int)
```

These initializers are *forwarded* from `ValueNode` and `ActionNode` by calls to `super.init()`.

In `ConstantNode`, I implement these initializers (note the change of signature between initializers no. 2 and no. 4).

```
3. public required init(factory: RandomTreeFactory, maximumDepth: Int)
4. public init(id: Int, maximumDepth: Int, constant: ValueType)
```

Here's a quote from Apple manual of Swift:

> Write the `required` modifier before the definition of a class initializer to indicate that every subclass of the class must implement that initializer.

**My question is this:** Why is it possible not to implement initializer no. 2 in `ConstantNode` in spite of it being marked as `required`?

**Secondary question:** Why does the compiler complain when I want to do the same in subclasses of `ActionNode` such as `SequenceNode` or `LoopNode`? Is it because of generics?

Thanks in advance,
Petr.

Comment: 1st question: because ConstantNode inherit the superclass initializer init(id:, maximumDepth) so the required is satisfied.